# execution of ternary operator

Tags: c, macros, operator-keyword, ternary

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define max(x,y)(x)>(y)?x:y

int main() {
    int i = 10;
    int j = 5;
    int k = 0;
    k == max(i++, ++j);
    printf("%d%d%d ", i, j, k);
    return 0;
}
```

I know the answer. It is `11 7 0` but how? please help me with the execution of the ternary operator.

Comment: using macros with side-effect expressions is a _bad_ idea. don't _ever_ write code like this. note: this has nothing to do with the ternary operator.

Comment: MSVC's `stdlib.h` already has the `max` macro - perhaps gcc has it too.

Comment: Are you sure of k == max(I++,++j)? '==' will check if 'k' > 0.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi; That's not UB for sure.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Using side-effect arguments is fine. The problem is if the side-effect argument is not evaluated exactly once.

Comment: ... in other conditional circumstances, not evaluated at all (short-circuit rule).

Comment: it is not my code.this question was asked in my examination.
and @Iharob Al Asimi I have executed this code its giving me the asnwer that i have mentioned.

Comment: @Abhijeetsingh: the fact that you get a result from compiling and executing the code does not preclude the possibility for undefined behavior. In this particular and peculiar example, the behavior **is** defined, albeit it takes advanced understanding of the language to prove... iharob was wrong, but so was I and haccks and Jean-François on some other subtle issues in this code.

Comment: @Abhijeetsingh: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 6):

The statement

```
k==max(i++,++j);
```

is expanded to

```
k==(i++)>(j++)?i++:j++;
```

Note that `==` has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `?:` operator and therefore the above expression is equivalent to

```
( k == ((i++)>(j++)) )?i++:j++;
```

Since `(i++)>(j++)` will be `true`, therefore `k == ((i++)>(j++))` is evaluated as `false` and hence `j++` (and it's value become `7`) will be evaluated (`i++` will be skipped).

---

**NOTE:** The above expression does not invoke undefined behavior because there exists [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) between the evaluation of the first operand of the ternary operator and the second or third operand. For example, the expression

```
a = (*p++) ? (*p++) : 0
```

has well defined behavior.

Comment: `10>6` is `false` ? how so?

Comment: (10>6).how it is false?

Comment: @Abhijeetsingh; Read the answer again.

Comment: Very good answer. Now one can wonder how such code can be written or which vicious teachers ask questions like that. Useless.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre; We have to admit it, it was a trick question ;)

Answer (score 2):

This question is definitely a trick question that will catch many unsuspecting C programmers. The different responders here have more than 100 years of compounded experience in C, yet it took several tries to get this right:

The expression  `k == max(i++, ++j);` expands to:

```
k == (i++)>(++j)?i++:++j;
```

Which is parsed as this (`==` has lower precedence than `>`, but higher precedence than `?`):

```
     (k == ((i++) > (++j)))
     ? i++ 
     : ++j;
```

The ternary operator evaluates the test `(i++)>(++j)`, which is true for the values in the program, hence evaluates to `1`, different from the value of `k`, so it proceeds to evaluate the third expression `j++`, which increments `j` a second time and returns the intermediary value `6`.  There is a sequence point between the test and the branch that is executed, so it is OK to increment `j` twice. The second branch is not executed at all since the test evaluated to false.

`i` is incremented once, its value becomes `11`.

`j` is incremented twice, its value is `7`.

`k` is not modified by the above statement, because `==` is the comparison operator, not the assignment operator.

Hence the output is `11 7 0`

**Notes:**

The program uses a macro `max` that evaluates its arguments more than once and they are not properly parenthesized in the expansion: 2 errors that illustrate the shortcomings of macros.  This macro should be names `MAX` to emphasize the fact that its arguments should not have side effects and its expansion should be fully parenthesized this way:

```
#define MAX(x,y) ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))
```

A better alternative is to make it an inline function:

```
static inline int max(int x, int y) {
    return x > y ? x : y;
}
```

If the program had this statement:

```
k = max(i++, ++j);
```

The output would be `12 6 11` because unlike `==`, `=` has lower precedence than `?` so the statement would expand to:

```
k = ((i++) > (++j))
    ? i++ 
    : ++j;
```

You can study the [table of operator precedence for C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). There are in my humble opinion too many levels and it is very difficult to memorize all of them, especially since some of them are rather counter-intuitive: print a copy and keep it handy or make a bookmark. When in doubt, use parentheses.

Comment: There is no UB in the expression.

Comment: @haccks: yes, I changed the answer, there is a sequence point between the test and the branch taken.

Comment: I have tested the code on gcc and to my surprise got same result as OP

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: yes, it took me while to figure `==` has higher precedence than `?` whereas `=` has lower precedence.

Comment: i am getting 11 7 0 as answer. i am running it on virtual compiler on geeksforgeeks.com

Answer (score 0):

You're using a double equal sign, which is a comparison. `k==max(i++,++j);` compares the return value of max to k, which is 0.

Instead, try changing the `==` to `=`.